# MySQL not able to start

Tags: mysql

Failed to start MySQL in Centos (command: service mysqld start). Getting "mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory" in my php application. And not sure it was crashed because of i accidentally set the root directory's ownership to root when installing an application. I tried to change the var/lib/mysql back to mysql:mysql, and removed the 3 ibd log files, but still no luck. And found the following error in the mysqld.log, and no more error log has been generated:

```
0x7f25c61fc700  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139800214488832 in 
file ut0ut.cc line 942
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
08:19:01 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
collection process might fail.

key_buffer_size=8388608
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=77
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 68195 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x35)[0xf52f35]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x4a4)[0x7d3754]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf7e0)[0x7f262e8c17e0]
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35)[0x7f262d3614f5]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x175)[0x7f262d362cd5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z18ut_print_timestampP8_IO_FILE+0x0)[0x7c28a8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN2ib5fatalD1Ev+0xb3)[0x11a2113]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16buf_page_get_genRK9page_id _tRK11page_size_tmP11buf_block_tmPKcmP5mtr_tb+0x1606)[0x11e3826]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z27btr_cur_search_to_nth_levelP12dict_ index_tmPK8dtuple_t15page_cur_mode_tmP9btr_cur_tmPKcmP5mtr_t+0x840)[0x11c5fe0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z29row_ins_clust_index_entry_lowmmP12dict_ index_tmP8dtuple_tmP9que_thr_tb+0x252)[0x10f1e62]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z25row_ins_clust_index_entryP12dict_index_ tP8dtuple_tP9que_thr_tmb+0xb8)[0x10f5f18]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z12row_ins_stepP9que_thr_t+0x35b)[0x10f828b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z15que_run_threadsP9que_thr_t+0x5b8)[0x10d5628]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z12fts_eval_sqlP5trx_tP10que_fork_t+0x2d)[0x128d25d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z14fts_write_nodeP5trx_tPP10que_fork _tP11fts_table_tP12fts_string_tP10fts_node_t+0x1f5)[0x126ef05]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x1277418]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z14fts_sync_tableP12dict_table_ tbbb+0x264)[0x127c7e4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z23fts_optimize_sync_tablem+0x3f)[0x127ed5f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z19fts_optimize_threadPv+0x16b)[0x12848cb]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7aa1)[0x7f262e8b9aa1]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f262d417c4d]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

And /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock become /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock.lock

i havent try the innodb force recovery, would it work if i delete the lock file and restart?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there enough free space on partion for mysql? Aslo check if there another running process `mysql` with `ps -aux | grep mysql` ?

Comment: Just checked, it failed because of a hardware failure. Now i can see new error. i think the databases are crashed.

Comment: The new error msg are : [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table abcdatabase/xyztable from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how to resolve the issue. There are almost 60% of my tables are "corrupted". i tried to google, but still no luck. i cant do mysqldump, i cant drop a table, i cant access any tables, but i can see all the databases & tables, when i run show Databases; command & show tables; command.

Comment: i have a weekly backup, so i have the structure & old data, i hope i can get back few tables (which is storing daily updates data).

Comment: i have added "innodb_force_recovery" in my.cnf, tested the value from 0 to 4. But no luck, is it recommend i go to 5 or 6?

Comment: I think is better way to ask your qestion on Database Administrator forum.